# forloop.counter problem with page pagination

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am very beginner in django. I have used `{% forloop.counter %}` for counting in HTML template.Its properly work in first page in html template but when I go to next page it again shows me form 1 to 5. I want to see results from the next one 6 to 10 .... How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Your question lacks some context. What is your code and where did you look to solve the problem?

Comment: Here is the similar question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69561266/django-foorloop-counter-restarts-in-a-new-page/69562000#69562000

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your page number in the queryparams, lets say your site is `localhost:8000` so you have to pass page like that: `localhost:8000/?page=2`.

Now you need to read that `page` param, and tell your forloop to start counting from next page.

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html good example

Comment: I am using normal html table, and I am having more than 1000 records to display. So,I used pagination concept and make 100 results per page.

The problem is, for the serial number column, Iam using forloop counter, for first page I got serial numbers as 1 to 100, for second page also I am getting serial numbers as 1 to 100.

What I need is, it has to be 101 to 200 for second page and for third page it has to be 201 to 300, but it is showing 1 to 100.

How to make serial number like I am expecting?

Comment: What is the problem? Knowing you are at page number 2, and the page size is 100, start counting from 2*100 + 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Django has quite a good [Pagination class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/), which you certainly could make use of.

To help more specifically, I think I'd need a little more code from your project (e.g. from the urls.py, views.py and template.html) to see what isn't working as hoped.

## EDIT

The simplest way is to follow the Pagination example that is mentioned in [Mikolaj's comment to his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62572673/6780677)

Alternatively, you could get your view to process which posts to display from a URL parameter. As an example:

```py
# when accessing /index.html?page=1
# views.py
def index(request):
    per_page = 100 # however many per page
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1)) # default is 1
    start_range = (page - 1) * per_page
    end_range = page * per_page
    records = YourModel.objects.all()[start_range:end_range]
    return render(request [...])
```

This would need to be smartened up, to make sure out-of-range pages are dealt with properly.
But the

Comment: I am using normal html table, and I am having more than 1000 records to display. So,I used pagination concept and make 100 results per page.

The problem is, for the serial number column, Iam using forloop counter, for first page I got serial numbers as 1 to 100, for second page also I am getting serial numbers as 1 to 100.

What I need is, it has to be 101 to 200 for second page and for third page it has to be 201 to 300, but it is showing 1 to 100.

How to make serial number like I am expecting?

Comment: See my edited answer. Sorry, but would need more of your code to help further.